# Ayuda en error PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema al cargar datos en web:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Modulos\class_buscar.php on line 41
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Modulos\class_buscar.php on line 41
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Modulos\class_buscar.php on line 42

Donde en el archivo `class_buscar.php` tengo esto que son las lineas 41 y 42:**

```
class Consultar_Profesor{
    private $consulta;
    private $fetch;
    
    function __construct($codigo){
        $this->consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM profesor WHERE doc='$codigo'");
        $this->fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($this->consulta);
    }
    
    function consultar($campo){
        return $this->fetch[$campo];
    }
}
```

y el archivo de `conexion` lo tengo asi:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,"basedatos1");
```

Ayuda por favor gracias

Comment: haces el includes de la conexion en el archivo class?

Comment: No estás accediendo a la variable conexión desde dentro de la función, o la pasas como parámetro, o la declaras dentro o la haces global y accedes a ella.

Comment: hago en include en la pagina principal. Y como paso el parametro o la hago global. Probe creando una clase global dentro del archivo class_ y nada??

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir en tu pregunta la clase de la conexion y el include a la misma?

Comment: el archivo de conexion lo tengo igual que el ultimo parrafo de la consulta, que no esta en clase

Comment: El problema que tienes es que `$conexion` no está declarada dentro de la clase, ni como variable ni como referencia. Por lo tanto está intentando acceder a una variable que no existe.

Comment: entonces tengo que crear una clase de conexion, y luego llamarla en cada una de las clases subyacentes???

Comment: Francisco lo estás haciendo al revés, je je. Lo ideal es tener una clase dedicada a la conexión, la cual llamarás cada vez que la necesites creando una nueva instancia de la misma.  Así, si necesitas usarla dentro de la clase `Profesor` creas una nueva instancia de tu conexión. Dicha clase debería ser capaz de manejar las consultas y devolver los resultados. [Aquí hay un ejemplo, pero con PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO).

Comment: hahah, es que tengo en el archivo class_buscar varias definiciones de clases con funciones especificas, o sea, tendre que cambiar todo mira tengo esto:  
class Consultar_Grado{
 private $consulta;
 private $fetch;
 
 function __construct($codigo){
  $this->consulta = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM grado WHERE id=$codigo");
  $this->fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($this->consulta);
 }
 
 function consultar($campo){
  return $this->fetch[$campo];
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se comenta el error es por la variable de conexión, a mi me pasaba mucho y tras probar varias formas opté por hacerlo algo parecido de como lo tienes tú, por una parte un archivo conexión donde están los datos igual que el tuyo.

Las clases lo mismo que tienes también, la única diferencia es que al instanciar una clase le paso la variable de conexión.

Por ejemplo en el método constructor de la clase que has mostrado sería así:

```
function __construct($codigo,$conexion){
        $this->consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM profesor WHERE doc='$codigo'");
        $this->fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($this->consulta);
    }
```

De este modo sólo tienes que modificar el argumento del constructor sobre lo que ya tenías. Prueba a ver.

Comment: Ese mismo realice y funciona, Gracias a todos

Comment: Francisco si solucionaste tú problema deberías marcar como respuesta aceptada aquella que te sirvió para que cuando otros lo vean sepan que se encontró solución. Ya que habrá gente que si no se visualiza que se encontró solución no entrar a ver el hilo.

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona porque las variables de conexión no las estás incluyendo en tu clase, o al menos así se ve en el código que has puesto.

Dado que lo estás haciendo con clases podrías tener un fichero conexion.php que contenga una clase para guardar los datos de conexión y luego invocar en tu clase `Consultar_Profesor`.

**Clase Conexion**

```
Class Conexion {

    protected $conexion_db;
    private $host = 'nombre_servidor';
    private $bd = 'nombre_base_de_datos';
    private $user = 'nombre_usuario_base_de_datos';
    private $pass = 'contraseña_usuario_base_de_datos';

    public function __construct(){

        try{

            $this->conexion_db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $bd);

            }catch(Exception $e){

                echo "Error en la conexión: " . $e->getLine();

            }
    }

}
```

**Clase Consulta Profesor**

Luego en tu fichero `Consultar_Profesor` llamarías a conexion de esta forma:

```
if(!class_exists('Conexion')) {

    include("includes/conexion.php");

}  

class Consultar_Profesor extends Conexion{

        function __construct($codigo){

            parent::__construct();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM profesor WHERE doc='$codigo'";
            $query = $this->conexion_db->query($sql);
            $resultado = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $resultado;

        }

        function consultar($campo){

            return $this->fetch[$campo];

        }

}
```

Para poder usarlo tienes que crear un nuevo objeto de la clase `Consultar_Profesor`en el fichero donde estés ejecutando dicho código.

**Ejemplo**

```
$consultaprofesor = new Consultar_Profesor($codigo)
```

Y luego ya usas dicho objeto como antes para poder generar la consulta.

Comment: Me salio eso jjj
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp2\htdocs\2014school\Modulos\class_buscar.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\2014school\Principal.php(8): Consultar_Profesor->__construct('12345') #1 {main} thrown in

Comment: no puedo corregir ese error

Comment: Lo he modificado, faltaba el constructor de la clase padre y la llamada al constructor a modo de ejemplo.